# rmarkdown equation in Word non-numbers are q‌u‌e‌s‌t‌i‌o‌n marks

Tags: r, rstudio, equation, r-markdown

In RStudio rmarkdown equation symbols not reproduced in Word. When I click Knit Word this

"$A = \pi*r^{2}$"

becomes this in the Word doc

"? = ? * ?^2"

no problem with html, pdf

Comment: R Markdown's equation output in Word isn't compatible with older versions of Word. I presume this is on Windows? What versions of R Markdown, Pandoc, and Word are you using?

Comment: Windows 7; R Markdown 0.3.10; Word 2007. Thank you I'll get Word upgraded.