# Bold inline equation in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, markdown

I am using Rmarkdown to produce a Word 2007 document on Windows 7. I want an inline equation within bold text. So when I knit:

```
**The units are in $m^2$**
```

I get "**The units are in** m^2". When I knit this:

```
**The units are in $\mathbf{m^2}$**
```

Word doesn't seem to recognize the symbols (displayed as ?) until I toggle back and forth from "linear" to "professional" equation or I copy paste the symbol back into document.

I see this previous question [rmarkdown equation in Word non-numbers are queston marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719753/rmarkdown-equation-in-word-non-numbers-are-queston-marks) here, but I have an updated Word version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
**The units are in** $\mathbf{m^2}$
```

or

```
**The units are in m^2^**
```

Comment: Would you also be able to answer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71778805/print-bold-text-conditionally-in-r-markdown/76218369#76218369