# Print bold text conditionally in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have an issue with R markdown when I try to print some bold text subject to a condition.

I want R to evaluate whether a string is empty or not. If the string is not empty it should be printed in bold. The final document is written in word. Here's the code that I have used:

```
myvar = "some string variable"

**`r if (myvar != "")  {myvar}`**
```

This code works fine when the string is not empty as it prints the variable correctly. If the string is empty, however, I expect no actions but the code returns a black line instead. I attached a screenshort of the final document, where you can see 7 black lines, one for each empty string evaluated with the previous code:

[image: Image depicting the problem]

Comment: By any chance have you found a solution to you problem? I'm just about to try the same.

Answer (score 0):

You may substitute myvar by pasting a string.

```
myvar = "some string variable"

`r if (myvar != "")  {paste0("**some string variable**")}`
```

However, if you need call a variable representing the string, I would not know how to have it bold, but **would delighted if someone could answer this**. I tried the following:

```
paste0("**myvar**")
paste0("**","myvar","**")
paste0(**myvar**)
```

But no success so far.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
myvar = "some string variable"

bolder <- function(x) {
  empties <- is.na(x) | is.nan(x) | x == "" | length(x) == 0
  paste0(
    paste0("**", x[!empties], "**", recycle0 = TRUE), 
    collapse = ", ")
}
```

`r bolder(myvar)`